# PHP snmpget() returns false. There is no such variable name in this MIB

Tags: php, snmp

The snmpget() function in my php code got error When the OID is "SNMPv2-MIB::sysORLastChange.0".

> Error in packet: (noSuchName) There is no such variable name in this
>   MIB.

But on the same server, I type a command:

```
snmpget -v 1 -c COMMUNITY HOST SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0
```

and got a correct response:

```
SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0 = OID: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.25506.11.1.35
```

I've checked that the arguments passed into the snmpget() function is correct but I have no idea why it returns false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HP A5120-series apparently do not support SNMPv2-MIB::sysORLastChange.0 (iso/1.3.6.1.2.1.1.8.0). Here is a snmpwalk over iso.3.6.1.2.1.1 of the 48-port-model. It stops at iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.7.0:

```
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 = STRING: "HP Comware Platform Software, Software Version 5.20.99 Release 2222P01
HP A5120-48G-PoE+ EI Switch with 2 Interface Slots
Copyright (c) 2010-2016 Hewlett Packard Enterprise Development LP"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0 = OID: iso.3.6.1.4.1.25506.11.1.36
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = Timeticks: (503780340) 58 days, 7:23:23.40
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 = STRING: "XXXXXXXXXXX"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0 = STRING: "XXXXXXXXXXX"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.7.0 = INTEGER: 12
```